# I'm trying to print a phrase in a line but there is an extra line-break in my do-while loop and I wonder why?

Tags: c, matrix, char, printf, line-breaks

Good evening, I created a word search program and my output should be in the form `"A palavra % está no texto!"` or `"A palavra % não está no texto!"`, however it looks like this:
A palavra NOITE
não está no texto!

My code is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 300
#define CHAR 20


int main(){
    int W, w; 
    scanf("%d ", &W); /*W is the number of words/lines in the matrix words*/
    char words[MAX][CHAR];

    for(w=0; w<W; w++){
        int c=0;
        do{
            scanf("%c", &words[w][c]);
            c++;
        }while(words[w][c-1]!= '\n' && c<CHAR);
    }
    
    /* the variable ultimate is declared in the complete code.In this example 
    the most important thing is the extra line-break in the output of the conditional if*/
    int ultimate=1, c=0;
    /*the variable l(line) is the line index of the word matrix. The c variable is the column index
    Supose that we have three words: words[0]=[NIGHT...000], words[1]=[SUN...000] and 
    words[2]=[MOON...000]*/
    int l=2;
    if(ultimate!=0){
        c=0;
        printf("A palavra ");
        do{
            printf("%c", words[l][c]);
            c++;
        }while(words[l][c-1]!='\0');
        printf(" está no texto!\n");
    }else{
        c=0;
        printf("A palavra ");
        do{
            printf("%c", words[l][c]);
            c++;
        }while(words[l][c-1]!='\0');
        printf(" não está no texto!\n");
    }                                
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to put all the phrase in a line but it isn't working. How I had to creat a type char matrix to register the words, I used a do-while loop to run print all the characters of the line the code is analizing. Each line of this matrix register a different word and fortunately it is working! So the real problem is the printf function...

P.s.: Sorry for the lack of the identation, the body of the question of this site wasn't recognizing my code.

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. Show us the exact input you give the program, and the actual as well as the expected output. Format both input and output as code.

Comment: Are you using `fgets` to read the word and not removing the newline at the end?

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I edited the question, I hope that it is better now! :)

Comment: Your input loop will not only read the newline from the user, but also store it in the array. You do something similar in your output loops, where you print the newline before detecting it and ending the loop.

Comment: What's worse, *much* worse, is that you look for the string null-terminator in your input, but you never actually add the string null-terminator anywhere in your code! That will mean your loops will go outside of the initialized parts of the arrays, where all values are *indeterminate* (it might be easiest to consider these as random or garbage). You might even go *out of bounds* of the arrays, which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

In light of the missing blocks of code and how the data is formed, there is only this:

Replace:

```
do {         
    printf("%c", palavras[l][c]);         
    c++;
} while(palavras[l][c-1]!='\0'); // see the ** note below
```

with:

```
for( c = 0; palavras[l][c] && palavras[l][c] != '\n'; c++ )
    putchar( palavras[l][c] );
```

This will terminate the loop when the end of the string OR a *newline* is encountered. This also uses the lightweight `putchar()` function instead of the heavyweight `printf()`.

** Notice that this `do/while()` first *tries* to print the `'\0'` before testing the character value? Not needed!

PS: Can you see the duplication of `printf("A palavra ");`?
Put **one** copy of this *ahead* of the `if()` statement to reduce duplication.

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice the duplication haha. Heavyweight functions are slower than the lightweights? Thanks for the tip and I will search more about the putchar. Thank you very much!